# Searching for value in enum

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I am trying to check if a string has any matching values defined inside Enum. For example, I want to print 'Found' in below code

I have added definitions of following implicit methods to support comparison, hashing and get methods

```py
from enum import Enum


class States(Enum):
    COMPLETED_STATE = 'completed'
    DEPENDENCY_WAIT_STATE = 'dependency_wait'
    FAILED_NO_RERUN_STATE = 'failed_no_rerun'
    IGNORED_STATE = 'ignored'
    RUNNING_STATE = 'running'
    NEVER_RUN_STATE = 'never_run'
    ON_HOLD_STATE = 'on_hold'

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) == type(other):
            return self.value == other.value
        return self.value == other

    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value


Map = {
    States.ON_HOLD_STATE: [States.NEVER_RUN_STATE],
    States.DISABLED_STATE: [States.NEVER_RUN_STATE],
    States.RUNNING_STATE: [States.DEPENDENCY_WAIT_STATE,
                           States.ON_HOLD_STATE,
                           States.NEVER_RUN_STATE],
    States.IGNORED_STATE: [States.RUNNING_STATE,
                           States.NEVER_RUN_STATE]
}


print(Map[States.RUNNING_STATE]) // ['dependency_wait', 'on_hold', 'never_run']
print(Map['running']) // ['dependency_wait', 'on_hold', 'never_run']
print(States.RUNNING_STATE == 'dependency_wait') // False
print(States.RUNNING_STATE == 'running') // True
print(States.RUNNING_STATE == States.RUNNING_STATE) // True 

if 'running' in States:
    print "Found" // Does not gets printed

if States.RUNNING_STATE in States:
    print "Found here" // Does not gets printed
```

Comment: Can you try removing yout overridden methods from the class and check again? Specifically the `__eq__` & `__get__` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta class of `Enum`, `EnumMeta`, defines the `__contains__` magic method to test if an `Enum` instance is a member of the given `Enum` class only based on the member's name, not value, so if you want it to be able to test memberships based on values, you would have to override `EnumMeta.__contains__` with a function that iterates through the values of the `_member_map_` dict attribute and compares each member value with the given test value to achieve that:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

def custom_EnumMeta__contains__(cls, member):
    return isinstance(member, cls) and member.name in cls._member_map_ or \
        any(m._value_ == member for m in cls._member_map_.values())
EnumMeta.__contains__ = custom_EnumMeta__contains__

class States(Enum):
    COMPLETED_STATE = 'completed'
    DEPENDENCY_WAIT_STATE = 'dependency_wait'
    FAILED_NO_RERUN_STATE = 'failed_no_rerun'
    IGNORED_STATE = 'ignored'
    RUNNING_STATE = 'running'
    NEVER_RUN_STATE = 'never_run'
    ON_HOLD_STATE = 'on_hold'

if 'running' in States:
    print "Found"

if States.RUNNING_STATE in States:
    print "Found here"
```

This outputs:

```
Found
Found here
```